# How do I create an empty Targetworksheet variable and update in the loop or is there better way than this?

Tags: javascript, excel, typescript, office-scripts

I'm new to programming and was playing around with Office script. Basically I have 4 worksheets with the same first column but they have different lengths. I want to it to get the column with the most rows from that worksheet and paste it into three new worksheets. The problem here is that I don't know how to create an empty targetworksheet variable and update in the loop. I also wonder if it can be updated through the loop. Is there a better way to do this?

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
  
  let maxRows = 0;
  let targetWorksheet = workbook.getWorksheet('Sheet 1');
  
  let worksheets = workbook.getWorksheets();
  for (let worksheet of worksheets) {
    let columnRange = worksheet.getRange("A:A");
    let usedRowsInColumn = columnRange.getUsedRange().getRowCount();

    if (usedRowsInColumn > maxRows) {
      maxRows = usedRowsInColumn;
      targetWorksheet = worksheet;
      
    }
    
    
    let usedRange = targetWorksheet.getUsedRange()
    let sourceRange = usedRange.getColumn(1);
    let columnvalues = sourceRange.getValues();

    let targetsheet1 = workbook.addWorksheet("sheet A");
    let targetsheet2 = workbook.addWorksheet("sheet B");
    let targetsheet3 = workbook.addWorksheet("sheet C");
    let targetsheetarray = [targetsheet1, targetsheet2, targetsheet3];
    for (let sheet of targetsheetarray) {

      let targetRange = sheet.getRange("A1:A" + columnvalues.length);
      targetRange.setValues(columnvalues)
  }
  }

        
}
```

it does not allow me to have an empty variable so I put something in and hope it will be updated after the loop but it didn't.